# Is there a way to achieve AI-like learning with SQL Server Full Text Search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, artificial-intelligence

I'm using FTS to index a description column for fast keyword matching. So imagine you search for 'foot', I would get back results for:

- football
- foothills
- footprint
- underfoot
- lightfooted

But as a user, lets say that invariably when I search for 'foot', I am seeking a particular record about football, 99% of the time that's the one I choose from the list of results. Is there anyway to weight this result in SQL Server so that it will come back as the first option?

I realize this is a broad question but I'm seeking directions to look in for more research for how to tackle this, thanks

Comment: Yes you can do something like this. There is <0% chance anybody can offer any help here though because there is no information about what you are trying to do. The direction you would take is based on a lot of things we don't know about here.

Comment: You are getting into something that  I think is outside the scope of SQL Server and is more towards search engine. This is the same thing of when you search for "burger king" other food related places come up, but "king arthur" doesn't.